# Why does Android-Chrome not clear Session Variables upon closure of the App?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, session-variables

First, let me say.  I like the new format.  Thanks Guys.

Ok,

I thought that I had it all figured out.  Unfortunately, Android hit me hard.  Android doesn't forget the last value of a Session Value.

If I close a browser in Windows, iOS, or Android, shouldn't it be expected to possess absolutely no relation between key and value, much less the EXISTENCE of a key?

Android is the only one that will retain that key and value for days.

WHEN A BROWSER CLOSES, SHOULDN'T THE SESSION VARIABLES CLOSE - DIE?

Until the Session Variable issue can be resolved, the involvement of other Session variables is pointless.

Page_Load(object o, EventArgs ea)
{

// granted, only in the android world
 // I know this is as redneck as redneck gets, but I tried

```
Response.Write("<script>alert(\""+Session["theVal"]+"\")</script>");
Session["theVal"]="Mickey Mouse";
```

// only in Android will that continually ring "Mickey Mouse", even if you close the browser down.

// the other browsers will ring 'null', error, or 'blank'

//  I hate Apple, but it even closes down the variable upon closure of the app.
}

Just suggestions.   I may be doing something completely wrong.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you close the browser in android. but it does not mean the app lost tracks of the web page. I have iOS for instance..you have to manually remove all the web pages which will be stacked one above the other. After you do that and then you open the chrome, all the sessions will be destroyed..I guess it is just the ay google made chrome for ios and android.